# Why after if-clause I always get current bar?

Tags: pine-script

My code finds local maximum. But I need to compare the last local maximum to the current bar and if its bigger to mark it. But here I have some problems.

```
//@version=3
study("MyScript", overlay = true)

localMax = if close[1] > close[2] and close[1] > close[0]
    close[1]

plotarrow(localMax, offset=-1)
```

It looks like there could be just anything instead "close[1]". I tried close[10], open, high and it gives the same result of the current bar so I need to use offset = -1. Is it a bug? A feature? How do I store a bar into a variable and then compare it another?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what problem exactly you have, but I see that you are setting a value of if-clause to the `localMax` variable. And the value is set when the condition is true, but if the condition is false, then localMax is set to `na`. So you must either add the else-clase or set a new value of `localMax` only inside if-clase (using assign operator `:=` rather than `:`).
First option works like that:

```
//@version=3
study("MyScript", overlay = true)

localMax = if close[1] > close[2] and close[1] > close[0]
    close[1]
else
    close

plot(localMax)
```

The second one:

```
//@version=3
study("MyScript", overlay = true)

localMax = 0.0
localMax := nz(localMax[1])
if close[1] > close[2] and close[1] > close[0]
    localMax := close[1]
plot(localMax)
```

> How do I store a bar into a variable and then compare it another?

I hope the next code solves your issue:

```
//@version=3
study("Max")

highestIndex = 0
highestValue = close

for i = 1 to 10
    if close[i] > highestValue
        highestIndex := i   // NOTE: operator := is important
        highestValue := close[i]

plot(highestIndex, color=green)
plot(highestValue, color=red)
```

NOTE: you can put an arrow (or change a value of a variable) only for currently being handled bar, you can't put an arrow N-bars in the past.

Comment: Last code example: 
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: line 7: mismatched input 'for' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

I also need to mark required bars so I think "plotarrow" will do better then just "plot". Anyway, it doesn't work.

Comment: Fixed a problem with spaces. This is just an example with plots, it supposed to help you to solve your problem, rather working code for you - that's what stackoverflow for.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Michel_T.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1910483/michel-t)

The following code shows local maximums those were higher then the previous local maximum. It is far away from perfect but it works.

```
//@version=3
study("Max", overlay = true)

highestIndex = 0
highestValue = close

for i = 1 to 10
    if close[i] > highestValue
        highestIndex := i
        highestValue := close[i]

x = if close[1] >= highestValue
    highestValue

plotarrow(x, offset = -1)
```